# onClick JavaScript Button

Tags: javascript, button, conditional-statements

I am kinda new person in JavaScript, please help me our here with small doubt

What I am missing here ........ I want to correct this one....

**I am trying this :**

```
if({!Account.CID__c}){
    window.open( '{! SUBSTITUTE($Setup.CustomSetting__c.Link__c,"[#CID#]",Account.CID__c)}');
}
else{
 window.open( '{! SUBSTITUTE($Setup.CustomSetting__c.Link__c,"[#CID#]",Account.AnotherField__C )}')
}
```

AND GOT ERROR :

> Now its giving me "Unexpected token )" error

**Earlier I was having**

```
window.open( '{!SUBSTITUTE($Setup.CustomSettings__c.Link__c,"[#CID#]",Account.CID__c)}');
```

**And I just want to add one more Condition here i.e.**

```
If(CID__C == null){
  // put another AnotherField__C in place of that.
}else{ 
   //put Account.CID__C ...which we were having earlier 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript null is falsey.  The ! operator before the statement will invert the comparison (ie, null will become true).  Therefore you could do just do something like this. Also, note how I used brackets.

```
If (!Account.CID__c) {
  //do something 
  } else {   
  //do something
}
```

You can also use 'else if' statements before the final else to nest additional parameters.

Comment: See updated question, Now its giving me "Unexpected token )" error

Comment: Make sure you don't have any extra {} or () in your if statement.  Can you post any more of your code?  For example, what Account.CID__c is?.

Comment: Nope I am sure about that, Its giving error when it goes in ELSE Condition, and For IF condition its still not opening the window with given CID__C

Comment: Unexpected token ) means javascript is seeing a ')' character where it wouldn't expect one.  Most likely you need to place a '}' character before the ')' character somewhere in your code.  Also, the console should tell you what line the error is taking place and the file name if you are using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me .... thanks to @Ashwani

```
if( '{!Account.CID__c}' == 'null' || '{!Account.CID__c}' == ''){
    window.open( '{! SUBSTITUTE($Setup.CustomSetting__c.Link__c,"[#CID#]",Account.AnotherField__C)}');
}
else {
    window.open( '{! SUBSTITUTE($Setup.CustomSetting__c.Link__c,"[#CID#]",Account.CID__c )}')
}
```